# XQuery count appearance of one element across all direct-parent nodes

Tags: xquery

In `XML` file:

```
<article>
   <title>This is book AAAA</title>
   <author>A</author>
   <author>B</author>
</article>
<article>
   <title>This is book BBB</title>
   <author>A</author>
   <author>C</author>
</article>
```

I need to use XQuery to output the author name if he/she appears in more than one `<article>`. In this case, author A should be outputted. Please note that one article can have multiple authors.

How should I write the XQuery?

Comment: I downvoted your question because I deem it not properly researched. With even a minimal research effort you should be able to write this question yourself as it one of the simplest examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to iterate over the distinct values of the entity you want to look up and then filter the query to your constraints using `where`:

```
let $authors := $data//article/author
for $author in distinct-values($authors)
where (count($authors[. = $author]) gt 1)
return $author
```

However, for large amounts of data `distinct-values()` may not perform well and implementation-specific methods of getting unique values may be required (e.g: using indexes).